# How to download files from command line?

Tags: linux, unix

For example, see this page [**Advanced Linux Programming**](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder).

I want to download all the `pdf` files linked from this page. Is there a simple commandline way of doing it?

Something on the lines of

```
download http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder *.pdf Downloads/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at wget

That site specifically says: "Do not use a download accelerator to download these files." so don't!

Comment: `wget` isn't really an accelerator, though (at least I think not), it's a plain old HTTP client, like a browser.

Comment: yeah, I read that, and am not using any accelerator. It doesn't matter if I use a browser or command line, does it?

Comment: well its upto you but the site also has a robots.txt that says no robots so you will need to use the -e robots=off option to disable robots.txt if you do

Comment: Lazer: By download accelerator, most people mean a program that starts multiple connections in parallel, usually to download separate chunks of the same file. This puts an extra burden on the server (and rarely speeds up the download since the N pieces come in at 1/N speed each). `wget` and `curl` are not download accelerators (unless used in an elaborate way) since they download files sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

You could use curl and wget, also check both man pages to see all the handy arguments you could use.